# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string', when using filter(Boolean) operator

Tags: angular, typescript

.ts:

```
siteName: string;

    this.store.pipe(
          select(getSiteName),
          filter(Boolean),
          take(1)
        ).subscribe(siteName => this.siteName = siteName);
```

Error:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

I'm getting the above error for `this.siteName`, after adding the `filter(Boolean)` operator to the pipe. Without the filter operator I didn't see any errors, am I missing something ??

Comment: what u want with this:  filter(Boolean)?

Comment: filter out null and undefined @ManuelPanizzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because TypeScript doesn't like you using the `Boolean` constructor as the predicate function passed into `filter`. It works if you switch over to an explicit predicate function, like this:

```
this.store.pipe(
    select(getSiteName),
    filter(x => Boolean(x)),
    take(1)
).subscribe(siteName => this.siteName = siteName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is referring to your parameter of the function subscribe which does not have any type

```
.subscribe(siteName => this.siteName = siteName);
```

correct would be:

```
.subscribe(siteName:string => this.siteName = siteName);
```

Comment: I'm curious, I'm getting that error after I added that filter operator to the pipe. Any idea ??